# regex: performance of lookbehind while still capturing data?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

In my project in C# I am parsing text for dates. The dates can be in various formats, objective is to find and correct a number of date format errors. Various date formats means a set of defined date formats isn't feasible. Originally I had a set of around 10 regexes applied one by one to the input string. This was functionally fine but when the string got towards 200 KB of text, performance became a problem as the function took about 150 ms.

I found I could improve performance considerably by applying the date regexes only to substrings that were dates. So if all dates had to have the English month name, using a regex of

```
\b(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\b
```

would find them. If I then did some substringing to get the text around the month matched, overall function performance was about 25 ms, so much better. However, the substring/loop, length check code is untidy and doesn't feel like a really good solution. What I really wanted was a single regex to match the month and text around it, something like

```
.{0,25}\b(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\b.{0,25}
```

is functionally fine. However, performance of this regex is about 3500 ms to find matches on the same long input string.

Now the similar regex

```
(?<=.{0,25})\b(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\b.{0,25}
```

with a positive lookbehind finds the matches in about 15 ms (due very reduced backtracking, reasons I accept and have some understanding of). However, that doesn't work for my use as I need the text before and after the month name to be included in the match result.

So, my question is, can I have a regex that has the performance of using the lookbehind, but the functionality of providing all the text within the match result?

Comment: y not make the date formats consistent at the first place..and if you can make the date formats consistent just do that instead of writing a `regex` that would **always** fail for some cases.. there are `n!`+ possibilities where `n` is the number of ways a date can be..

Comment: You can simply capture the lookbehind and concatenate it to the match: `(?<=(.{0,25}))`. You'll find the contents of the lookbehind in `Groups[1]`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

The performance gain is an illusion. Normally, something like `.{0,25}` will cause a lot of backtracking, which explains the poor performance that you're seeing. When placed inside a look-behind, however, it stops behaving greedily and backtracking, the look-behind will look for the smallest possible match, which means that **0** characters will be tried, with no backtracking. This means that the look-behind is completely useless since it will always match zero characters before the month name.

What if you extract the context after you find a match on the month name by using the position of the match? For each [`match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in `regex.Matches(str)`, get [`match.Index`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.index.aspx) and [`match.Length`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.length.aspx) and substring before and after those positions.

Comment: Yes, that's effectively what I'm doing at the moment. The overall functionality is correct, performance pretty good, but the solution feels untidy to me, also have to check start/end of article when substringing. I'm hoping to find a solution with good performance while still being able to use a MatchEvaluator, which is the approach I've used successfully in other parts of the application and seems to result in tidy code. Though maybe it's not doable within the constraints I've outlined.